Why Is not working get_reset_password_router in FastAPIUsers?
Try to register router for reset password in FastAPIUsers, but get this error:
  File "/Users/alexm/Downloads/Dev/news_minds/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi_users/router/reset.py", line 57, in forgot_password
    await user_manager.forgot_password(user, request)
  File "/Users/alexm/Downloads/Dev/news_minds/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi_users/manager.py", line 381, in forgot_password
    self.reset_password_token_secret,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'UserManager' object has no attribute 'reset_password_token_secret'. Did you mean: 'reset_password_token_audience'?

I did everything in the documentation
But I redefined the UserManager like this
class UserManager(IntegerIDMixin, BaseUserManager):
    async def validate_password(self, password, user):
        if len(password) < 8:
            raise InvalidPasswordException(
                reason='foo'
            )
        if user.email in password:
            raise InvalidPasswordException(
                reason='bar'
            )

    async def on_after_register(self, user, request=None):
        print(f'foobar')

I use FastAPI == 0.115.5 / FastAPIUsers == 14.0.0
If you look at what is being scolded, it gets weird, because the attribute is defined inside the BaseUserManager
class BaseUserManager(Generic[models.UP, models.ID]):
    """
    User management logic.

    :attribute reset_password_token_secret: Secret to encode reset password token.
    :attribute reset_password_token_lifetime_seconds: Lifetime of reset password token.
    :attribute reset_password_token_audience: JWT audience of reset password token.
    :attribute verification_token_secret: Secret to encode verification token.
    :attribute verification_token_lifetime_seconds: Lifetime of verification token.
    :attribute verification_token_audience: JWT audience of verification token.

    :param user_db: Database adapter instance.
    """

    reset_password_token_secret: SecretType


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You don't have a constructor in UserManager and therefore without putting the Parent's constructor in the UserManager's constructor, you won't have access to the parent's attributes.

This question, how come there is no access to parent attributes ?
Aren't they inherited?

They are only inherited only if you initialize the parent's __init__()

I honestly don't really understand how it should work, when inheriting, attributes are inherited as well.
You mean do this?
def __init__(self):
super().__init__()
Can you explain?

I'm learning myself...  but maybe this might help https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-the-role-of-parent-classs-init-in-python-inheritance/

Oh, I do def init(self):  super().init(), but also don't work (

You're meant to set reset_password_token_secret when you inherit - the secret needs to be app specific and not part of the library. It's just there for documentation purposes.
From the UserManager examples:
class UserManager(UUIDIDMixin, BaseUserManager[User, uuid.UUID]):
    reset_password_token_secret = SECRET  # use two different, securely generated random values here
    verification_token_secret = SECRET

In Python, a class attribute without a default value is never set as an attribute - it can be a slightly surprising behavior in Python, but it allows you to document what values are expected to be overridden/set.
>> class Foo:
...   bar: str
... 
>>> Foo()
<__main__.Foo object at 0x740f517fdf70>
>>> Foo().bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar'

While a default value changes that behavior:
>>> class Foo:
...   bar: str = "baz"
... 
>>> Foo().bar
'baz'


Thank you very much, it's very clear !
I didn't see it in the documentation..
